# Issue with extra '/n' text when rendering a csv with pandas and flask

Tags: pandas, flask

I'm trying to read a csv with Pandas and render the results (top 50 rows) as a table with flask. The table comes out fine but there's some extra text on the top of the table. There is also way more if I print the whole table. I don't think it's a problem with the csv since I made a dummy dataframe with 2 rows/columns and it had the same issue. Code and output is below:

main.py

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file).head(50)

return render_template('index.html', data=[df.to_html(classes="data")])
```

index.html

```
<div>
  <h1> CSV File </h1>
  {{ data | safe }}
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, had to remove the square brackets around `df.to_html(classes="data")`